# Is there an OpenLDAP web frontend that allows users to edit custom fields?

Tags: ldap, openldap

We are currently using a custom perl based frontend for our OpenLDAP user portal, and it's proving tricky to port over to a new server. I've setup phpLDAPadmin on the new server, but it doesn't appear to be aimed at allowing users to edit their own LDAP info.

We have some custom fields,such as for Public SSH and GPG keys, and I need a way to allow users to update their public key stored in LDAP. Does anyone know of a program that would allow for users to login and update their LDAP information? There are plenty of password update tools, but none that I can find allow editing of other fields.

Comment: do you have any plan to create a new web application ?

Comment: I don't, as I'm not adept enough at any particular language to make one myself. It's possible that I can patch up the old one enough to make it work, but I'd prefer to have something that is more widely used in case I need help with it.

Comment: The usual expectation is that if you implement custom fields, it is also up to you to provide the path to modifying them. Short of writing a new frontend or having users log in to one of your servers and run scripts, this is not likely to be a fruitful search.

Comment: Well with a tool like phpLDAPadmin, you can write a template that allows you to edit a custom field. Surely something like that exists elsewhere.